# error Failed to run jetifier. while going to run react native app on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm unable to run my react native app on my physical device. It was working fine todays morning also.

error Failed to run jetifier.
Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Ashish Nath\Desktop\react native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\jetifier\bin\jetify
at makeError (C:\Users\Ashish Nath\Desktop\react native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\Ashish Nath\Desktop\react native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async Object.runAndroid [as func] (C:\Users\Ashish Nath\Desktop\react native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:104:7)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Ashish Nath\Desktop\react native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: put more info, that not help also restart cache and put what commands you are running

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.